# Use of specifying lengths for surrogate keys

Tags: database, performance, oracle

In one of my database class assignments, I wrote that I specifically didn't assign lengths to my NUMBER columns acting as surrogate keys since it would unnecessarily limit the number of records able to be stored in the table, and because there is literally no difference in performance or physical storage between NUMBER(n) and NUMBER.

My professor wrote back that it would be technically possible but "impractical" for large databases, and that most DBAs in real-life situations would not do that.

There is no difference whatsoever between NUMBER(n) and NUMBER as far as physical storage or performance goes, and thus no reason to specify a length for a NUMBER-based surrogate key column. Why does this professor think that using NUMBER alone would be "impractical"?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, most production DBAs in real life would likely do as you suggested and declare key columns as NUMBER rather than NUMBER(n).

It would be worthwhile to ask the professor what makes this approach impractical in his or her opinion.  There are a couple possibilities that I can think of

Assuming that you are using a data modeling tool to design your schema, a reasonable tool will ensure that the data type of a key will be the same in the table where it is defined as a primary key and in the child table where it is a foreign key.  If you specify a length for the primary key, forcing the key to generate foreign keys without length limits would be impractical.  Of course, the counter to this is that you can just declare both the primary and foreign key columns as NUMBER.

DBAs tend to be extremely picky (and I mean this as a compliment).  They like to see everything organized "just so".  Adding a length qualifier to a field whether it be a NUMBER or a VARCHAR2 serves as an implicit constraint that ensure that incorrect data does not get stored.  Ideally, you would know when you are designing a table a reasonable upper bound on the number of rows you'll insert over the table's lifetime (i.e. if your `PERSON` table ended up with more than 10 billion rows, something would likely be seriously wrong).  Applying length constraints to numeric columns demonstrates to the DBA that you've done this sort of analysis.

Today, however, that is rather unlikely to actually happen at least with respect to numeric columns both because it is something that is more in keeping with waterfall planning methods that would generally involve that sort of detailed design discussion and because people are less concerned with the growth analysis that would have traditionally been done at the same time.  If you were designing a database schema 20 or 30 years ago, it wouldn't be uncommon to provide the DBA with a table-by-table breakdown of the projected size of each table at go-live and over the next few years.  Today, it's more cost effective to potentially spend more on disk rather than investing the time to do this analysis up front.

Comment: Also, surrogate keys will often have holes in the key values so that the largest surrogate key will be larger than the number of rows held in a table. This is especially true with the larger cache values on sequences being specified to get good performance on RAC. So you wouldn't want NUMBER(10) just because you don't expect to handle more than (10e10)-1 records.

Comment: @Shannon - True.  But it would be unlikely that you'd have more holes than data on a moderately active table so you'd be pretty safe in saying there are 6 billion people in the world, even if we got every one of them to sign up and 4 billion more that are yet to be born and we averaged a gap of 5 between rows, a NUMBER(11) should still be sufficient.

Comment: If the surrogate key is used in output (eg as a reference number for correspondance) I'd still put a maximum size on it, just so you've got a firm idea what space you'd need in the letter (or screen) to display the value.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better from a readability and self documentation standpoint to limit what can be stored in the column to numbers that are expected. I would agree that I don't see how its impractical

[From this thread about number](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1619552483055)

> number(n) is an edit -- restricting the number to n digits in length.
>
> if you store the number '55', it takes the same space in a number(2)
>   as it does in a number(38).
>
> the storage required = function of the number actually stored.

Answer (score 0):

Left to my own devices I would declare surrogate primary keys as NUMBER(38) on oracle instead of NUMBER. And possibly a check constraint to make the key > 0. Primarily to serve as documentation to outside systems about what they can expect in the column and what they need to be able to handle.

In theory, when building an application that is reading the surrogate primary key, seeing NUMBER means one needs to handle full [floating point range of number](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00222), whereas NUMBER(38) means the application needs to handle an integer with up to 38 digits.

If I were working in an environment where all the front ends were going to be using a 32 bit integer for surrogate keys I'd define it as a number(10) with appropriate check constraint.